# Complex integration related to finite temperature number density correlation function of 1d free fermion

Tags: integration, special-functions

I am looking for an explicit formula for this complex integral.
$$\oint_C \frac{d z}{2 \pi i} \frac{z^{-(x+1)}}{1+e^{-\beta(z+1 / z-\mu)}},$$
where $x\in \mathbb{Z},\  \beta,\mu\in \mathbb{R}\ $. The integration path $C$ is the anti-clockwise unit circle on the complex plane.
This integral can be evaluated with the residue theorem and the generating function of the Bessel function of the first kind.
$$i^x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{k\beta\mu}J_x(2ik\beta)$$
I would like to calculate this infinite summation as an alternative.

Comment: Did you try the case $\mu=0$?

Comment: In $\mu=0$ case, the integral becomes proportional to $\exp(-x/\xi)$ where $\xi=\{2\log[\sqrt{(\pi/2\beta)^2+1}+\pi/2\beta]\}^{-1}$, but I couldn't prove this either.